# Understanding Baryonic Acoustic Oscillations

Tags: cosmology, astronomy, oscillators, baryons

I was reading the book of Barbara Ryden "Introduction to cosmology":

In the chapter number 9, in the page 203. She  says:

> "The photons, electrons, and protons together make a single photon-baryon fluid, whose energy density is only about a third that of the dark matter.
> Thus, the photon-baryon fluid moves primarily under the gravitational influence of the dark matter, rather than under its own self-gravity.
> [...]

> "If the photon-baryon fluid finds itself in a potential well of the dark matter, it will fall to the center of the well.
> As the photon-baryon fluid is compressed by gravity, however, its pressure starts to rise.
> Eventually, the pressure is sufficient to cause the fluid to expand outward.
> As the expansion continues, the pressure drops until gravity causes the photon-baryon fluid to fall inward again."

**Question**

As far as I understand the Dark matter don't interact with the electromagnetic radiation, so my intuition say that the " Dark matter potential  well" will increase his size as time pases. So, every time the photon-baryon photon fluid enters to the "potential well", it will take more time to get out ?

I mean the Baryonic acoustic oscillations are not  some kind of harmonic oscillaton, they are more like some kind of damped oscillation?

Comment: The size of the wells grows with the universal expansion, and the dark matter also evolves under its own gravitation. I think the overall effect is that the wells get gradually deeper.